# Is it possible to use SQLite and ORMLite without android?

Tags: sqlite, ormlite

If I would like to develop a small desktop application using java + ORMLite, would it possible to use ORMLite without android?

Comment: Seems like the docs would be the first place to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ORMLite supports JDBC connections, so yes it's possible.

> ORMLite supports JDBC connections to MySQL, Postgres, H2, SQLite, Derby, HSQLDB, Microsoft SQL Server, and can be extended to additional ones relatively easily. ORMLite also supports native database calls on Android OS.

Links:

- [ORMLite Documentation - PDF Format](http://ormlite.com/docs/ormlite.pdf)
- [ORMLite Getting Started Page](http://ormlite.com/docs/getting-started)
- [ORMLite JDBC Repository with Examples](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc)

Comment: Thanx @Pedro Rodrigues